# Web 8.5 Deployer Error when Publishing

Tags: content-delivery, deployer, oracle

**Background:**

We have configured a basic microservices setup for a *preview* environment. We are able to start all the microservices (session content, preview, discovery, deployer-combined), which are running on a Linux box. We've implemented a very basic topology, to allow one Target Type to use for publishing. We're running all databases on Oracle RAC and we have several content brokers, each corresponding to a different web application, as several sites' content is being managed in the same Tridion CMS instance. Our CD databases are copies of Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 databases that we've updated to Web 8.5, and we are planning to use the updated broker database for the state store.

**Error:**

When we attempt to publish something very basic, like a simple component, the publishing package gets placed in the incoming folder, but then we immediately get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [04/13/2018 17:00:31.882] [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://ProcessingAkkaSpringContext/user/$a] Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:430)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.setExecutionState(Unknown Source)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.ExecutionActor.storeStatus(ExecutionActor.scala:75)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.ExecutionActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ExecutionActor.scala:52)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
        at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.ExecutionActor.aroundReceive(ExecutionActor.scala:22)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:247)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:189)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
 )
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
        ... 39 more
```

We suspect the issue is with our deployer-conf.xml. Because we are running Oracle RAC databases, we're not sure how to complete the storages section. We've tried many different combinations, but nothing seems to work:

```
<State>
  <Storage Adapter="oracle" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver">
    <Property Name="host" Value="<our_host>" />
    <Property Name="port" Value="<our_port>" />
    <Property Name="database" Value="<our_service_name>" />
    <Property Name="user" Value="<our_db_user>" />
    <Property Name="password" Value="<our_db_password>" />
  </Storage>
</State>
```

It is not clear what these fields should be, since other parts of the documentation say to use "serviceName" instead of "database" for Oracle RAC, etc. And we're wondering whether we need something like here as well:

```
<Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
<Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
```

A few other things to note:

- The CMS is still DXA 1.2, as we have not yet been able to
  successfully run the upgrade script for DXA 1.7/1.8. But my understanding is that this should not affect publishing.
- The Linux box we're using for the microservices is CentOS. We are aware that the requirement here is Redhat, but we've consulted with several parties that tell us CentOS should be fine for this environment.
- There are one or two other microservices to install, but again, I don't think it should affect publishing (CID, context).
- We haven't run the script to switch from old to newly published statuses. Again, I don't see how this would affect us at this point.
- Our topology uses some stubbed values for the website/web application/mapping, which are not in place yet.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if this could be because we're missing the latest hotfix(es): http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/#/hotfixes/c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it turns out we were indeed missing a Content Delivery hotfix. We installed the latest cumulative CD hotfix (CD_8.5.0.9057), which solved our issue. The specific hotfix that originally caught our attention was CD_8.5.0.3300, as its problem description was exactly the issue we were seeing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Oracle connectivity issues.

Try to verify following to fix that issue.

1. Ensure your Microservice server installed oracle client and the **tnsnames.ora** file configured and file that contains network service names mapped to connect descriptors for the local naming method, or net service names mapped to listener protocol addresses. A net service name is an alias mapped to a database network address contained in a connect descriptor
2. Verify that connection from that server by **sqlplus** a command to ensure that connection that user credentials are working as expected.
3. Ensure the **deployer-conf.xml** DB state storage configured as highlighted with your environment credentials details.

   ```
   <State>
       <Storage Adapter="oracle" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" generateDDL="true">
           <Property Name="host" Value="localhost"/>
           <Property Name="port" Value="1523"/>
           <Property Name="serviceName" Value="sdlcddev"/>
           <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser_Staging"/>
           <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxxxx"/>
       </Storage>
   </State>
   ```

   4. Ensure the **cd_storage_conf.xml** DB storage configured as highlighted with your environment credentials details.

```
            <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="ORACLESQL"
                Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
                <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                <DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                    <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
                    <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost"/>
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1523"/>
                    <Property Name="serviceName" Value="sdlcddev"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser_Staging"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="xxxxx"/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
```

I hope it helps.